# vanilla javascript function based on screen resize

Tags: javascript, function, resize

I am trying to execute a function by resizing the window. The function is changing the color of the body based on screen resizing. If the screen size is less than 500px body should be in 'Red', else it should be 'Green'. I wrote a function, but it is not working in resizing. It works only after refreshing the browser. I want to execute the function without refresh. Following is the code. Thanks in advance for anyone's help.

HTML:

```
<div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
<div class="content">This is the Toggle Displaying content</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
doit=()=>{
if(window.innerWidth<500) {
document.body.style.background="red";
}
else {
document.body.style.background="green";
}
}
doit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
doit = () => {
    const fn = () => {
        if(window.innerWidth<500) {
            document.body.style.background="red";
        }
        else {
            document.body.style.background="green";
        }
    }
    fn()
    window.addEventListener('resize', fn)
}
doit();
```

Comment: ```
window.addEventListener('resize', doit)
```
i tried the above code. But when i open the browser it is not working but working once i started to resize the window. Any solution for this.

Comment: ```
window.addEventListener('resize', doit)
```
i tried the above code. But when i open the browser it is not working but working once i started to resize the window. Any solution for this.

Comment: add ```doit()``` before the event Listener

Comment: Hi Rateb, your answer is fine.  I'll mark your answer is solution. But before that let me ask you that, is there any other solution to make everything inside in the function itself. Just asking.

Comment: sure, I'll edit the answer

Comment: Hi Rateb, Thank You! You are awesome, i'm a Designer let me know you need any help in design things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event listener on window resize

```
document.addEventListener("resize", function (e) {
    if(window.innerWidth<500) {
        document.body.style.background="red";
    } else {
        document.body.style.background="green";
    }
});
```